Redirect URL with folder to another URL using .htaccess
I want to deliver content from an alternate site without showing the other URL in the browser.
My mainsite is mainsite.com
My content is at contentsite.com/assets/videos
I tried using Apache ReWrite to do this, but it isn't working
I want to redirect all calls to mainsite.com/downloads/ to redirect to contentsite.com/assets/videos/
On mainsite.com I want to have a link (but neither the folder nor file exist here) like:
mainsite.com/downloads/video1.mp4 but I want to browser to deliver the content (ideally without showing the contentsite.com url in the browser) from
contentsite.com/assets/videos/video1.mp4
When I enter mainsite.com/downloads/video.mp4 in the browser, instead of the expected redirect, I am getting a 404 not found.
This is what I'm using so far in my .htaccess.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mainsite.com
RewriteRule ^downloads(.*) http://contentsite.com/assets/videos$1 [P]

Thanks

You are actually not implementing a redirection at all. You are implementing a proxy. Just to get the naming straight ;-)

Not sure if that is a typo, but you should be clear about how that content folder on your backend server is named, video or videos. Your question is contradicting itself in that.

Are you sure that you actually loaded and activated the two apache modules proxy and proxy_http? Both are required for that rule to work.

Thanks for the clarification, I used to use domain cloaking for this. The names in the sample, are just generic sample folders :)
I'll look at the proxy thing and come back.
